# How do I find the view_name and view_display_id of a View Block in Drupal 9

Tags: ajax, drupal

Is the view_name the same name as Machine Name in Drupal? I'm trying to render a view using Ajax in Drupal 9.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The View_display_Id is the machine name of the view (emebed_5) and view_name is found in Structures -> View -> machine name. I also changed the url to Drupal.url('views/ajax') and it worked!